# highcharts tooltip not working after zoom

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with the highcharts column range tooltip after zoom in. 
Basically after I zoom in (zoomType:'xy') on the column range chart, for some columns the tooltip shows up, while some others the tooltip just simply refuse to popup. I tried debug into it and the tooltip.positioner function didn't get called.

To [try it](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/).

copy the following and run it.

```
$(function () {
    window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: true,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            data: [
                [-9.7, 9.4],
                [-8.7, 6.5],
                [-3.5, 9.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Now try to zoom and you'll notice sometimes the tooltip on some specific column wouldn't show up.

Any advice?

Comment: It appears, because tooltip has position in centre of point, and in case when you zoom, then position of it is out of plotarea. So you can use tooltip positioner and define correct position. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner

Comment: Actually I tried the positioner and it still doesn't work, highcharts thinks it's outside of the plot area still.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem, and solved by setting the **followPointer** attribute within **tooltip**:

```
tooltip : {
    followPointer: true
}
```

refer to: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.followPointer